# Permissions not working using django-guardian for djangorestframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-guardian

I am trying to add object level permission to my django REST project using django-guardian, but I am getting

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tasks/

HTTP 403 Forbidden
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}

The user joe is logged in.

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'guardian',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',

    'task.apps.TaskConfig',
]
```

models.py:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    content = models.TextField()
    reported_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_task', 'View task'),
        )
```

serializers.py:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

permissions.py:

```
class CustomObjectPermissions(permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions):
    perms_map = {
        'GET': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'OPTIONS': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'HEAD': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'POST': ['%(app_label)s.add_%(model_name)s'],
        'PUT': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'PATCH': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'DELETE': ['%(app_label)s.delete_%(model_name)s'],
    }
```

filters.py:

```
class DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter(BaseFilterBackend):
    perm_format = '%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'
    shortcut_kwargs = {
        'accept_global_perms': False,
    }

    def __init__(self):
        assert 'guardian' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS, (
            'Using DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter, '
            'but django-guardian is not installed.')

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        from guardian.shortcuts import get_objects_for_user

        user = request.user
        permission = self.perm_format % {
            'app_label': queryset.model._meta.app_label,
            'model_name': queryset.model._meta.model_name,
        }

        return get_objects_for_user(
            user, permission, queryset,
            **self.shortcut_kwargs)
```

views.py:

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    permission_classes = (CustomObjectPermissions,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter,)
```

urls.py:

```
router = DefaultRouter()

router.register('tasks', TaskViewSet, base_name='tasks')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

But it works fine in shell

```
> python manage.py shell -i ipython
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [2]: joe = User.objects.all().filter(username="joe")[0]

In [3]: import task.models as task_models

In [4]: task = task_models.Task.objects.all()[0]

In [5]: joe.has_perm('view_task', task)
Out[5]: True
```

Answer (score 4):

The API first [checks model-level permissions](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/7c6e34c14f54f1bf0d46ff34dc9a823215987c95/rest_framework/views.py#L385-L402), then [object-level permissions](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/7c6e34c14f54f1bf0d46ff34dc9a823215987c95/rest_framework/generics.py#L77-L103) if they apply. Since the custom permissions class requires the user to have read-permissions, you need to ensure that Joe has been assigned model-level read access. If you check  `joe.has_perm('tasks.view_task')`, I would bet that it returns `False`. To fix this, you either need to directly assign his user the permission, or add him to a group that has been assigned the appropriate permissions.

Also, note that Django 2.1 recently added the ["view"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#model-view-permission) permission, and it shouldn't be necessary to add it to your models anymore.